# How to capture the packet from same machine with tcpdump on Linux?

Tags: linux, tcpdump

My computer has only one network card. I have a program listening on one port. I intend to send one packet on the same machine, my program can receive the packet. I can't capture the packet by tcpdump on the machine which my program is running on.

If I send packet from another machine, tcpdump can capture the packet.

Comment: Is my description not clear? My question is on hold state for a long time. I edited my question once, but it still keeps on hold state.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you send the packet from a machine to itself.
If so, you need tcpdump on the loopback interface.
e.g.

```
tcpdump -i lo
```